# How to disable a button if a text field is empty?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to disable the continue button if there is nothing in the text field. 
Here's my code...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var nounTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var `continue`: UIButton!

var noun = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func continueButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    noun = nounTextField.text!
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let nvc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
    nvc.noun2 = noun
} 
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, always call `super` in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

since you've already made your class a UITextFieldDelegate ad this function

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if !text.isEmpty{
        continueButton.userInteractionEnabled = true 
    } else {
        continueButton.userInteractionEnabled = false 
    } 
    return true
}
```

also update your viewDidLoad function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nounTextField.delegate = self
    if nounTextField.text.isEmpty{
        continueButton.userInteractionEnabled = false 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting an error where it is continue.userInteractionEnabled. It says consecutive statements on a line must be seperated by a ;

Comment: It says consecutive statements on a line must be seperated by a ;

Comment: I noticed in your code the continue variable has single quotes around it 'continue'.  I don't think swift likes that.  might want to remove the single quotes.

Comment: come to think of it continue is a reserved word in swift.  You will probably need to change the button name to something else.  Maybe continueButton

Comment: Three observations: Rather than modifying `userInteractionEnabled`, I'd just toggle `enabled`. Second, the `text` property of `UITextField` is optional, so you have to unwrap it when you cast it to a `NSString`. Third, you can reduce that `if`-`else` clause to simply `continueButton.enabled = !text.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Rob, I appreciate the comments on my suggested solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Just an fyi to future readers: This delegate method is not called when setting the textfield's text programmatically. If you have a code path that sets the text manually/without a keyboard, you will need to handle that separately

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5 version**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let oldText = textField.text else {
        return false
    }
    
    let newText = (oldText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    continueButton.isEnabled = !newText.isEmpty
    return true
}
```

Comment: `let newText = (oldText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)` can _alternatively_ be written as `let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: Range(range, in: oldText)!, with: string)`, avoiding casting; thanks to the fact that Foundation extends `String` to expose methods defined by `NSString`.

Answer (score 2):

@Steve's answer is the way to go in my opinion. We can further optimize the emptiness detection with probably faster checks:

```
continueButton.isEnabled = (!replacementString.isEmpty || range.length < (textField.text ?? "").count)
```

This may be provided as a UITextField extension :

```
extension UITextField {
    func changeDoesNotLeadToEmptyString(replacingCharactersIn range: NSRange, with replacementString: String) -> Bool {
        return (!replacementString.isEmpty || range.length < (text ?? "").count)
    }
}
```

I tested many cases including Cut/Paste operations, and it seems to work ok. I'll correct my answer if I found issues during further testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if nounTextField.text == ""{
  continueButton.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if nounTextField!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).isEmpty ||
                    nounTextField.text == nil{
`continue`.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: Where should this go?

Comment: First, set the delegate of the text field to self in viewDidLoad since you're already subclassing UITextFieldDelegate by doing this: nounTextField.delegate = self, then add this nounTextField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged) which will give it a target to go to when the text field value is changed, finally create the function with the name given, in this case func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){//insert code here}

Answer (score 0):

If there is an 'all clear' button in the text field, you should also implement the method below . Because the 'shouldChangeCharactersInRange' method is not called if you clear your textfield with the 'all clear' button.

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    yourbutton.isEnabled = false

    return true
}
```