# Disable Button if TextField is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I need make button disabled if TextField is empty. Otherwise it crashes my app

> (*Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*).

I know, here people wrote many times about it. But I tried many examples from StackOverflow like:

```
if (MyTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
MyButton.isEnabled = false
MyButton.alpha = 0.5
}
```

Above code I did put in viewDidLoad and it's didn't work.
If I put for button like:

```
@IBAction func acceptButton(_ sender: Any) {
if (MyTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
MyButton.isEnabled = false
MyButton.alpha = 0.5
...
```

Then button always disabled. Even I put some numbers in TextField.

Below code is also doesn't work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
MyTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionTextFieldIsEditingChanged), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
...
}
...
 @objc func actionTextFieldIsEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        if sender.MyTextField.isEmpty {
            MyButton.isEnabled = false
            MyButton.alpha = 0.5
        } else {
            MyButton.isEnabled = true
            MyButton.alpha = 1.0
        }
 }
```

Other part of codes I cannot use because it's from 2014-2015 year.

Comment: Where and how does it crash?

Comment: You should use UITextFieldDelegate method like textFieldShouldReturn. This method will be called on return button pressed.

Comment: @meaning-matters thanks you. Updated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206648/how-to-disable-a-button-if-a-text-field-is-empty

Comment: Another way would be to check upon the tap of the button if the `UITextField` is empty, if it is set the button to do nothing, if it is not let it perform your code.

Comment: Note: When writing swift variable names should be lower camel cased. Only types should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UITextFieldDelegate` method `shouldChangeCharactersIn` for this.

First bind your class with `UITextFieldDelegate` like this

```
class ClassName: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ...
```

Then add this code to your `viewDidLoad`

```
myTextField?.delegate = self
MyButton?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
MyButton?.alpha = 0.5
```

And implement this delegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        if !text.isEmpty{
            MyButton?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            MyButton?.alpha = 1.0
        } else {
            MyButton?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            MyButton?.alpha = 0.5
        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` method to enable button when there is text in text filed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       myTextField.delegate = self
   }

}
```

Implement this delegate method...

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate { 


  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if let text = textField.text, text.isEmpty {
        MyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        MyButton.isEnabled = false
        MyButton.alpha = 0.5
    } else {
       MyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        MyButton.isEnabled = true
        MyButton.alpha = 1
   }

  }

}
```

You can disable button in viewDidLoad method as well.

```
if let text = MyTextField.text, text.isEmpty {
    MyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    MyButton.isEnabled = false
    MyButton.alpha = 0.5
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also enable and disable button as user types in textfield.

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {  

  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if text.isEmpty{

        MyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        MyButton.isEnabled = false
        MyButton.alpha = 0.5

    } else {

        MyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        MyButton.isEnabled = true
        MyButton.alpha = 1
   }

    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to write two functions: `enableButton(_ button: UIButton)` and `disableButton(_ button: UIButton)`.

Comment: Thank you. But then my button always disabled

Comment: Don't negate `!text.isEmpty`, simply swap the `if` and `else` block and remove the `!`.

Comment: both the same, just makes my button disabled :(

Comment: That code should work, but (a) it builds strings only to test their length, and it uses `NSString`, which is discouraged from Swift. The solution in my answer does the same calculation without building a throw-away string.

Answer (score 1):

First set

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btn.isEnabled = false
}
```

then in textfield delegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    print(textField.text?.count ?? "default")
    if textField == MyTextField
    {
    if MyTextField.text?.count == 1 && string == ""
            {
                MyButton.isEnabled = false
            }
            else
            {
                MyButton.isEnabled = true
            }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func acceptButton(_ sender: Any) {
  if (MyTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
    print("i am not doing anything")
   }
  else{
      //perform the code
  }
 }
```

Comment: Some feedback: You don't need brackets around an if, your missing a curly bracket before else, you shouldn't force unwrap, you shouldn't need to force unwrap for an if, it's better to use the textfield delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a complete answer to this, so here goes:

1. iOS has the strong convention that variable names and function names should start wit lower case letters. Only classes and types should begin with upper-case letters. Thus in the code below I've changed `MyButton` to `myButton` and `MyTextField` to `myTextField`.
2. Don't use `isUserInteractionEnabled` and `alpha`. Just set the button's `isEnabled` flag and let UIKit decide how to draw the disabled button. That way you follow the normal HIG conventions for showing a disabled button.
3. Add code to your `viewWillAppear(_:)` function to disable the button if the text field is empty.

Like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myButton.isEnabled = (myTextField.text?.count ?? 0) > 0
}
```

4. Make your view controller conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. Then control-drag from the text field onto the view controller to connect up the delegate link.
5. Add a `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` function to your view controller to disable the button if the text field is empty. Note that this function has to figure out if the text field will be empty after the replacement is complete, so it needs to calculate the length of the field's text after the string is replaced. You can add your `UITextFieldDelegate` functions in an extension to your view controller, which separates them out nicely.

Like this:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, 
      shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
      replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        //Make sure this method is being called
        guard textField == myTextField else { return true }
        let newLength = (textField.text?.count ?? 0) - range.length + string.count
        myButton.isEnabled = newLength > 0
        return true
    }
}
```